# How do i print a value in my markup from the code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have this code in my markup:

```
<form id="myfileupload" action="/_layouts/IrvineCompany.SharePoint.CLM/aspx/Upload.ashx?ProjectApprovalId=" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If you look at the url in the action property:

```
/_layouts/IrvineCompany.SharePoint.CLM/aspx/Upload.ashx?ProjectApprovalId=
```

I want to be able to add a number at the end of ProjectApprovalId from a variable in the codebehind file.  How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you can post the form to itself and then, in code-behind, do:

```
...
Response.Redirect ("/_layouts/IrvineCompany.SharePoint.CLM/aspx/Upload.ashx?ProjectApprovalId=" + yourVariableName);
...
```

It will redirect to the handler and you can pass whatever you want as QueryString

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

/_layouts/IrvineCompany.SharePoint.CLM/aspx/Upload.ashx?ProjectApprovalId=***`<%=VariableName%>`***

Comment: Agree with desigeek but you may have to declare the variable in the code behind page as public: `public string VariableName = "";`

Comment: @itruman: Maybe but you only need a Property if you have processing, such as a calculated value or validation in the class. In fact, coding a Property can be slightly more trouble. Which is why I said "you may" in my comment. All the code is not in the question, so I had to guess. Either way, it has to be declared first.

Comment: @jen: I strongly disagree with you on _you only need a Property if you have processing_.  **A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a private field**. You are right though, we can only guess what is better for this particular case. That's why I said "rather" :)

Answer (score 1):

From an ASP.NET point of view you will have to make the form object a server-side object to access it in codebehind.

like

```
 <form runat="server" id="form1">
```